# Google Script SendEmail doesn't send complete message

Tags: google-apps-script

I used a google script in order to send e-mails.

Here is the code below.

n=29, so there are 28 e-mails to be sent.
For each row "message" is a text which is a concatenate of several data from other sheets.

For instance :

- for "message" of the row 2 is written "Hello team A2, here is the list of non compliant items B2,C2,D2"
- for "message" row 3 could be "Hello team A3, here is the list of non compliant items  B3,C3"

I noticed that the e-mails are sent correctly only for 19 rows (with all the B,C,D items non compliants correctly mentioned, as in the ggsheet) whereas for 9 rows, for a reason I can't explain it's not correct. For these 9 rows sometimes there is no items name at all (example for row 2 instead of message above, we have "Hello team A2, here is the list of non compliant items") but sometimes we have only partial names (example for row3 instead of message above, we have "Hello team A3, here is the list of non compliant items B3"

Could you help ?

```
 function sendEmail() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('TEXT');

var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

var subject = "Critical Corso 8h"

var n=sheet1.getLastRow();

for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {

var emailAddressTL = sheet1.getRange(i,4).getValue();

var ServiceAcquired=sheet1.getRange(i,3).getValue();

var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();

message=message.replace("<service>",ServiceAcquired);
if (emailAddressTL == "") {
  continue
}

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddressTL, subject, message);


}

}
```

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your sheet you're working with. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('TEXT');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var subject = "Critical Corso 8h"
  var n = sheet1.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) {
    var emailAddressTL = sheet1.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    var ServiceAcquired = sheet1.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var message = sheet2.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
    message = message.replace("<service>", ServiceAcquired);
    if (emailAddressTL != "") {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddressTL, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

Please provide a table of data but redact private info